# According to Chebyshev's rule, how many observations should lie within one and a half standard deviations of the mean?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, standard-deviation, descriptive-statistics, stationary-processes

Using the formula : $p = 1 - k^{-2}$

I calculated that $p = 1 - 1.5^{-2} = 0.56$ , which equals to $56\%$.

Because I have $24$ data points I go ahead and solve the number of points is $56\%$ of $24$:

\begin{equation}
\frac{56 * 24}{100} = 13.44
\end{equation}

which is approximately 13, which was my final answer.

For some reason this is not the final answer therefore my answer 13 is wrong.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: cher, Welcome to Physics SE! Perhaps consider formatting the question so that your reasoning is a little clearer.

Comment: What is the alleged "final answer"?

Answer (score 1):

By Chebyshev's inequality,

$P(|X-\mu|\geq k \sigma) \leq \frac{1}{k^2}$

$\implies P(|X-\mu|<k\sigma)>1-\frac{1}{k^2}$

For $k=\frac{3}{2}$, we have R.H.S. bound as $\frac{5}{9} \approx 0.5555556$, so that number of data points $=24 \times \frac{5}{9}\approx 13$

By Chernoff's inequality, we can get stronger tail bounds:

- $P(X\geq \mu +k\sigma) \leq e^{-k^2\sigma^2/3\mu}$ and
- $P(X\leq \mu - k\sigma) \leq e^{-k^2\sigma^2/3\mu}$

$\implies P(|X-\mu| <k\sigma) > 1-2e^{-k^2\sigma^2/3\mu}$

Answer (score 0):

When you calculate the *p* do not round up, instead it'll just be (55%*24)/100=13.33 which is the correct answer.

Comment: Hi Juls, welcome to Maths SE. Isn't  $p$ = .55 also a rounded value?